# to stop the rotation of the motor using push button even when the Bluetooth is connected

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-ide

I am using Arduino Nano, Bluetooth module HC-05 and one push button.
I want to rotate the motor when it receives signal from the Bluetooth and stop the rotation when the push button is pressed but here the Bluetooth signal should not be disconnected the motor should stop its rotation when BLuetooth is connected and the button is pressed.
The problem is when signal is passed through Bluetooth or serial , the motor rotates but when we push the button to stop the rotation the motor doesn't stops.
Below is what I tried.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(10,6);
const int  buttonPin = 5;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int  motorPin = 9;
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;       // the pin that the LED is attached to
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int Data;
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.println("Send 1 to open LOCK. Send 0 to close LOCK");
  Serial.println("Send 1 to open LOCK. Send 0 to close LOCK");
  delay(1000);
  Bluetooth.println("Waiting for command..."); 
  Serial.println("Waiting for command..."); 
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

if (Bluetooth.available())
{  
    Data=Bluetooth.read(); 
    if(Data=='1'){
      Serial.println("Motor rotating");
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
    }

      if (Data=='1' and buttonState == 1){
      Serial.println("Motor stop");
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

    }
    else{;}
}
}
```

I tried only to control with the push button only which works well. When the button is pushed it motor stops and when unpushed it rotates.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following problems with your code

1. The variable Data you defined as integer but you are comparing it with string '1'
2. In your first if condition you are not checking button status before rotating motor, make it

   if(Data==1 && buttonState == 0)

Otherwise both the condition will execute when buttonState =1, which will give unexpected result of starting and stopping the motor intermittently.